# Intellij IDEA 12.1.6 - hibernate doesn't resolve table or column name

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm writing my first webapp on IDEA. I'm having a small problem with model classes. IDE can't resolve a names of tables, columns, attributes, ect. from a database and marks this as errors. I DO have a Data Source configured (even on IDE scope). Do anybody know how to bypass that (while having a working project of course :))?
As in title, I'm using an IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6 version.

Comment: Why does it bother you? The project works, doesn't it? I just ignore those red highlightings

Comment: @Raul Why ignore the red highlightings, and allow actual problems to hide among them? That's not a good approach.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please [check the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-hibernate-support.html):

> In the Data Sources Mapping section, specify the data source for each Hibernate session factory. To do that, select the desired entry in the Session Factory column, double click the corresponding Data Source, and select one from the list of data sources already configured in your workspace.

[image: assign data sources]

[image: assign dialog]

Comment: You have to [change](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/9403/sm1x.png) `<none>` to the data source that you have [previously configured](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/7643/ep01.png).

Comment: The data source keeps resetting to "none", and I can't tell why.